# Как расположить текст слева от картинки,сохранив картинку по центру?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка расположена по центру при помощи `margin 0 auto`, как расположить текст ниже так, чтобы он был ровно слева от картинки, не обтекал ее, а был на одном уровне и рядом с ней.

То,как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: конечно покажите как должно быть, а не как есть сейчас, а то плохо понятно что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно так реализовать.

Мощный инструмент `grid`

Родитель при помощи свойства ***`grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;`*** разделяет свое пространство на три части, не смотря на на то, что контент состоит из двух элементов и получаем нужный результат

```css
* {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas quaerat sapiente saepe ipsa nihil. Harum, placeat! Mollitia ab perspiciatis atque debitis! Vero, rem iusto accusamus illo voluptatum culpa laboriosam? Cum!
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/33ff99/555555?text=FOTO" width="200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let left = document.querySelector('.left');
let right = document.querySelector('.right');
document.querySelector('.image').onclick = ()=>{
  if(!left.classList.contains('hidden')&&!right.classList.contains('hidden')){
    right.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  else if(!left.classList.contains('hidden') && right.classList.contains('hidden')){
    left.classList.add('hidden');
    right.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
  else if(left.classList.contains('hidden') && !right.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    right.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  else {
    left.classList.remove('hidden');
    right.classList.remove('hidden');
  }

};
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30vw;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: right;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  width: 30vw;
  user-select: none;
}
.image{
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  background: url('https://unsplash.com/photos/dqulzxRF31M/download?force=true&w=640');
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 33vw;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="right">
  чётко по центру и с margin: 0 auto; Нажмите на картинку!!!
</div>
<div class="image">

</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо <3